# Can I install Xamarin Android 10.0 with Visual Studio 2017 Pro?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-10.0

I need to update Visual Studio 2017 Pro to use Xamarin Android 10.0, so that I can install Android SDK 10.0 (API Level 29).

Currently, Xamarin Android 9.1.7.0 is installed. It says Visual Studio is up to date, and doesn't prompt to install Xamarin Android 10.0.

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.0),
VS 2019 is supported, but VS 2017 is not mentioned. Does this mean I need to run VS 2019 to be able to install Xamarin Android 10.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Does this mean I need to run VS 2019 to be able to install Xamarin Android 10.0?`

Yes, you should Update to Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or later. If you are using Visual Studio for Mac 2019, update to Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.3 or later.For more details you can refer to the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-10#get-started

After that, you should set the Repository to `Google` like following screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, good to know. Microsoft needs to think about organisations which cannot easily upgrade their version of visual studio to the latest and greatest at the drop of a hat. The Community Edition license doesn't cover us either so that's ruled out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, you can proposed this feature idea to this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html thread

Comment: Thanks but this is not an idea for VS 2019, rather for VS 2017 support for Xamarin Android 10.0

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot. You must upgrade to Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio for Mac 2019.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/servicing#support-for-older-versions-of-visual-studio